# Django editing view/template for Froala form

Tags: django, forms, django-templates, froala

I wanna use [Froala editor](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/) (or similar editor) for creating and editing articles in my site. I can create any article with this form/can get data from editor, but i don't know how to insert article data from DB through view function into `{{ form }}` of editor in my template. How to do this? Are there other more suitable forms/editors for this case?

forms.py

```
from froala_editor.widgets import FroalaEditor
    
class FroalaModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        content = forms.CharField(widget=FroalaEditor)
    
        class Meta:
            model = FroalaModel
            fields = ('name', 'content')
```

views.py

```
def post_froala_form(request):
    form = FroalaModelForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.name = request.POST['name']
        form.content = request.POST['content']
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:froala_index'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/froala template.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

froala_template.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
    Froala template
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'polls:post_froala_form' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.media }}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit">Send form</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please post code for context on what you're doing that's not working.

Comment: Ok, already done

Comment: from the looks of it, if form is valid, you're not passing the `form` variable into the redirect. Another is in the `else` statement. You're missing the underscore there. If this is from your source code, it should break. However, in your question, there is indication stating that fact. This may or may not be the missing item.

Comment: Thanks for the review. This code works for me, but this is not the point. In addition, I want to add the functionality of data editing that are already recorded, but I don’t know how to do it, so I don’t have a code who try to do, for this I created this question. Usually I realize this by inserting variables with data into the attribute `value` of the `<input>` element, but here is no input, there is only a `{ form }`. For Froala, I know how to get recorded data, I know how to record new data, but I don’t know how to insert the recorded data in the form to edit it in this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided this with Django Forms, indicating in the parameter "instance" a field from the database:

views.py

```
def question_create_update_form(request, question_id=None):
    if question_id:
        question = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)
        if question.author_name == request.user.username:
            form = AddQuestionForm(instance=question)
            return render(request, 'polls/add_question.html', {
                'title': question.question_title,
                'choices': question.choice_set.all(),
                'tags': question.tag.all(),
                'question_id': question_id,
                'form': form

            })
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:create_question'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/add_question.html', {
            'form': AddQuestionForm
        })
```